# Start application to open docx in a comment location

Tags: c#, openxml

Is it possible to use the OpenXml API to open a document file in a specific spot, like, for instance, in specific comment location, with the default application to open .docx files (or other application if specified)? I know you can use either `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to open a word file or the `Process.Start`, but I need to open the document in a specific location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Explanation given in the following MSDN forum thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5ea089c9-76fc-49fe-ae33-718fab110eac/start-application-to-open-docx-in-a-comment-location?forum=oxmlsdk&prof=required

> As far as I know, you could not open a word application with Open XML
>   SDK, Open XML SDK is used to operate the data which stored in the
>   file. I suggest you use Word automation to open a word file.
>
> I think you could create a bookmark named as “B1” in the position of
>   the comment, you then use
>   “word.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,"B1");”
>   to go to the comment after you open the file. A simple code as below:
>
> ```
>     public static void goToBookMark()
>     {
>         Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
>         word.Documents.Open(@"D:\OfficeDev\Word\Edward.docm",true);
>         word.Visible = true;            word.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,"B1");
>     }
> ```
>
> For more information about Selection.GoTo, you could refer the link
>   below:
>
> Selection.GoTo method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.goto(v=office.15).aspx